# Proactive API requests with Angular and Spring

Tags: angular, spring, http, tomcat, angular-httpclient

In my angular web app, I have multiple components with each of them having some drop-downs. The backed API request-time for each drop-down change is quite lengthy. So for better UI experience I decided to proactively fetch data for few mindful drop-down combinations. For better design, I extracted cache management to a service, through which calls for backend APIs happen (Components => Cache Manager => Backend API). So in Cache Manager I have a wholistic view on all API requests that happen in my app (might be useful info).

I setup the stage for all this, and in comes `Chrome max 6 TCP connections for same origin` rule to spoil the party. The challenge here is I have two categories of requests proactive and high-priority. I consider a request high-priority if it has to delivery the data for current UI render function. As of now I don't have any control on how the two categories of requests happen. If more than 6 proactive request happen, the high-priority requests are stalled by Chrome which is resulting in delayed rendering.

**My Attempt:**
I remember `Connection: Keep-Alive` header of HTTP and concept of requesting multiple resources over the same HTTP connection. However, I couldn't relate them to the frameworks I am using. Can I send multiple API requests over same HTTP connection in angular using angular's HttpClient? And How does app server (Tomcat) handles it? Will it process multiple requests over same HTTP connection parallelly or sequentially? Will this attempt change anything? I am open for other designs for this problem.

Comment: Please, let me know if additional details are needed :)

Comment: I am happy to get partial answers, So I could pursue further.